# How to enable create permissions for relationships in a Microsoft Dynamics Managed Solution

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I have two reasons for asking this.

1. I've used a managed solution in the past that has created relationships after it was installed.
2. The MSDN site [Use managed properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309297(v=crm.6).aspx) says that three properties exist that allow 1:N, N:1, and N:N relationships to be created on a managed entity.

   - Can be related entity in relationship - CanBeRelatedEntityInRelationship.Value (Read Only)
   - Can be primary entity in relationship - CanBePrimaryEntityInRelationship.Value (Read Only)
   - Can be in many-to-many relationship - CanBeInManyToMany.Value (Read Only)

That seems great, but when you follow instructions and go to "Managed Properties" on an Entity in a Solution that is unmanaged, those three attributes do not exist.

My theory is that I could set them in the solution XML, but I'm not certain if there is a proper supported way. Has anyone done this, or can point to a resource on how to do it? Also, as supporting documentation, [this technet page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531052(v=crm.6).aspx) shows the Manage Properties options that exist, which excludes the above mentioned.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ? Do you want to prevent others from relating to your entities ?

Comment: I want to have a managed solution, but allow relationships to be created.

Comment: AFAIK mnaged solutions do not (I'd go as far as saying they *cannot*) prevent that, did you create a managed solution and after the import you can't create relationships ? In that case, post the details of the scenario you are facing. As is, the question is unclear.

Comment: Correct - I have created managed solutions in the past, and they throw an error when attempting to create a relationship. For instance, a N:1 requires a field to be created _in_ the managed entity, and it fails because it cannot create the field.

Comment: And to head up the question before it appears - yes, it is possible to create a lookup to another entity in a Managed Solution - the EchoSign managed solution does this for instance. I'm assuming it is related to the permissions listed in my question.

Comment: Don't look in "Managed Properties", the relationships are visible in the solution if you expand the entity in a separate item for each type of relationship.  And the way to use security to enable creating relationships is setting the Append and Append To permissions.

Comment: How does a security role help me to create a relationship in a managed solution? A managed solution cannot be modified unless you say it can in "Managed Properties", and that is an all or nothing change. Not related to only relationships being allowed to be created.

Comment: You generally should not be making changes to the managed solution (that's the whole point of them - if you want to change them, use unmanaged solutions).  Make the changes to the entity/security role in your dev environment where nothing is managed, and package the solution up as managed for higher environments.  This should be allowed and achieve your desired functionality.

Comment: And the security roles help you create relationships with actual records, I didn't realize you meant you were trying to create the "relationship" in terms of the data model, I thought you meant you were creating records (actual data) related to each other.

Comment: My entire question is _how_ do I create a managed solution that allows relationships to be created. I've seen managed solutions where this is enabled, and Microsoft details a few related security fields, but doesn't explain how to actually do it. I'm not modifying other managed solutions.